# Почему не работают табы в React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Не выходит запустить работу табов в React( Ни сами табы не переключаются, ни активный класс на кнопках не срабатывает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yitwhz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас есть компонент Page, который хранит в себе стейт `activeTab` активного таба, а также метод изменения стейта `setSelected`.

`setSelected` вы должны биндить к `Page`, вы же его биндите к компоненту `CardList`

Comment: Большое спасибо!